# Using Tshark in Python Subprocess is giving syntax error

Tags: python, subprocess, tshark

I am trying to develop a script to read pcap file and extract some field from it but using tshark as a subprocess. However i am getting syntax error regarding cmd. Can anyone help me out on this?

```
def srcDestDport (filename):
  cmd = r"tshark -o column.format:"Source","%s", "Destination","%d", "dstport"," %uD"' -r %s"%(filename)
  subcmd = cmd.split(' ')
  lines = subprocess.Popen(subcmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  return lines
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as Python is concerned, you appear to be missing some commas in your `cmd` definition:

```
cmd = r"tshark -o column.format:"Source","%s", "Destination","%d", "dstport"," %uD"' -r %s"%(filename)
#              -- no comma here -^                              ----^  ----^     --^
```

because the first string *ends* when the first `"` is encountered at `"Source"`; a raw string does not preclude you from escaping embedded quotes.

If you wanted to produce a list of arguments, just make it a list directly, saves you interpolating the filename too:

```
cmd = ["tshark", "-o", 
       'column.format:"Source","%s","Destination","%d","dstport"," %uD"',
       "-r", filename]
```

Note the *single quotes* around the 3rd argument to preserve the quotes in the command line argument.

This eliminates the need to split as well and preserves whitespace in the filename.

Comment: def srcDestDport (filename):
       cmd = ["tshark", "-o",
                 'column.format:"Source","%s","Destination","%d","dstport"," %uD"'
                       "-r", filename]
         #subcmd = cmd.split(' ')
         lines = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
         return lines

When i try to like this, this time i am getting 

tshark: Invalid -o flag "column.format:"Source","%s","Destination","%d","dstport"," %uD"-r"

error

Comment: One more question if add "|", "sort","|","uniq" i am getting sort was unexpected in this content error.

Comment: You are not executing these commands in a shell (which would normally take care of pipes; `sort` and `uniq` are separate UNIX commands); sort the content in Python instead.

Comment: mistake :) i didnt realize until you warned.